# How do I revert back my changes in compiz opacity settings?

Tags: compiz

While I was playing with opacity window settings in compiz, I set all windows to complete transparent, so I can not see anything on the screen. I logged in to another user account.
Would anybody tell me how to find opacity settings in compiz and modify it from another user session?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for asking such a simple question. For noobs like me here how I fixed it. 
I navigated to user directory from another user session and renamed compizconfig

```
mv ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig  ~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig.old
```

and when I logged into my current session windows can be seen.